# HTML - Não consigo alinhar uma textarea, todos outros itens estão alinhados

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
<body>
<table class="Cabecalho" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="33%"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></th>
        <th width="33%"><a href="PaginaContato.html">Atendimento</a></th>
        <th width="33%"><a href="Empresas.html">Empresas Filiadas</a></a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="textored centro"><br>
    Empresa
    <br><br>
<select required>
    <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
    <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
    <option value="NVIDIA">NVIDIA</option>
    <option value="Oi">Oi</option>
    <option value="Vivo">Vivo</option>
    <option value="Tim">Tim</option>
    <option value="Claro">Claro</option>
    <option value="NET">NET</option>
</select><br><br>
    Assunto
    <br>
<select id="assunto" onchange="f(this)">
    <option value="info">Informações</option>
    <option value="elog">Elogio</option>
    <option value="recl">Reclamação</option>
    <option value="suge">Sugestão</option>
    <option value="outro">Outro</option>

</select><br><br>
<div id="mOutro" style="display:none"></div>
<textarea  rows="5" cols="40" id="tOutro" style="display: none;"></textarea><br id="pulaLinha" style="display:none">


    Digite sua mensagem <br><br>
<textarea required rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>

<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="botao()";">Enviar</button><br><br>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url("http://www.forhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/technology-wallpapers-hd-and-technology-background-22.jpg");
        }

        .Cabecalho{
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            border-style: dashed;
            text-align: match-parent;
            border-color: darkorange;
        }
        a:link {
            color: darkorange;
        }
        a:hover{
            color: orange;
        }
        a:visited{
            color: #ff5f1c;
        }

        .textored {
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

        }
        div {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .centro{
           text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function f(g){
        if(g.options[g.selectedIndex].value == 'outro'){
            document.getElementById('mOutro').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mOutro').innerHTML += "Especifique seu assunto <br><br>"
            document.getElementById('pulaLinha').style.display = 'block'
            document.getElementById('tOutro').style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('mOutro').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('mOutro').innerHTML = ""
            document.getElementById('pulaLinha').style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById('tOutro').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    function botao(){
        document.getElementById('submit').onclick = location.href='PaginaFim.html';

    }
</script>
```

Todo o código está no mesmo arquvio.

Quando o assunto da tag  (ID: assunto) for "outro" ira surgir uma textarea pedindo para especificar melhor o assunto, e essa textarea (ID: tOutro) não está alinhada com a div.

Já tentei usar text-align: center; na tag mas não funcionou e estou sem ideias.

Caso queira testar para entender com mais facilidade o que estou dizendo:

https://repl.it/Hxbj

apenas coloque o assunto como outro para visualizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione ao seu css a regra para o `id="tOutro"`

```
#tOutro{margin: 0 auto;}
```

E vc tem um erro de sintaxe na seguinte linha:

```
<th width="33%"><a href="Empresas.html">Empresas Filiadas</a></a></th>
```

Tem uma end tag `</a>` sobrando...

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!